# Laravel confused if I should use <form> tag or not when doing a ajax put request

Tags: laravel

I am making a simple put request to my app backend using `axios.put();`
This all works, I have a button that is binded to vue like `@click="submitForm"`

However looking around I see that some people still wrap their input fields in forms like those:

```
<form method="POST" @submit.prevent="onSubmit" action="{{ route('someRoute') }}" id="form-submit">
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Even if I dont use a form like the one above I get the same result when calling my ajax put request.

Laravel allready adds csfr headers to axios by default in **resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js**

So is there any reason I still should wrap my inputs in a form like above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax request doesn't matter if you do your inputs in form tags or not, because the request still sends and receives data from a server.
I would use a form tag because everybody can read the markup much easier and it could be usefull for writing less code in javascript - one example

```
<form action="" method="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Input</label>
    <input type="text" name="input" />
  </div>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#some-form').on('submit', function() {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    ... do whatever you want (like ajax call) ...
    return false;
  });
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an Ajax request, in which case a standard "form submit" would get prevented. Putting a `form` around it is not obligatory, especially if you use a `button` element, which is not a classic form element anyway.